# Preferred format to store a date in Wordpress custom post (meta) (pluginn development)

Tags: wordpress, date, datetime, custom-fields

For a booking plugin I need to store dates (start date and end date) for each booking. I want to store bookings in a custom post type, so I do not need to make my own tables in the database.

So I will store the dates in a meta.

I could store the date in mysql format, Ymd, or unix timestamp. But which way is best? Which way would be the Wordpress way?

ps: would this also work best for dates stored in settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [querying `BETWEEN` custom `DATE` meta fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), WordPress requires the date format to be `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you plan on using a `compare` argument of `BETWEEN`, I recommend storing in this format. Otherwise, it really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this format everywhere else also, to keep life simple.